# SAS Prediction - No Valid Observations

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to use a fitted regression model to predict an average balance for a specific zip code based on certain values: 
Avg Age - 34, 
Avg Education - 13 Years, 
Avg Income = 89000, 
Avg Homevalue - 160000
Avg wealth - 140000

I have the following code, but keep getting the 
Error: No valid observations are found.

And my output shows Number of Observations Read - 1, Number of Observations Used - 0, Number of Observations with Missing Values - 1, but I'm not sure what is missing.

```
TITLE "Assignment 5 - Banking";
data banking;
infile 'S:\Assignment4\Bankingfull.txt' delimiter='09'x MISSOVER;
input age education income homeval wealth balance;
run;

proc print; 
run; 

TITLE "Correlation Values"; 
proc corr; 
var age education income homeval wealth balance; 
run; 

TITLE "Scatterplots"; 
symbol value =dot color=black; 
proc gplot;
plot balance * (age education income homeval wealth);
run; 

TITLE "Regression"; 
proc reg; 
model balance = age education homeval wealth
    /clb;
plot student.*predicted.;
plot student.*(age education homeval wealth);
plot npp.*student.;
output student=resid;
run;

TITLE "Residuals";
proc reg; 
model balance = age education homeval wealth/stb;
run;

TITLE "Predictions"; 
data pred;
input balance age education income homeval wealth; 
datalines; 
. 34 13 89000 160000 140000
;
data new; 
set pred bank;
run;

proc reg; 
model balance = age education homeval wealth/p clm cli; 
run;
```

Comment: PROC REG needs a QUIT, not a RUN, but none of PROC REG have a DATA statement either. I would suggest adding that.

Comment: And...your data set is called BANKING not BANK - this is a simple typo error. ` data new; set pred BANKING; run;` will probably fix your issue.

Comment: omg, embarrassing.  I can't believe I didn't catch my typo. :/. thank you so much for your help and patience :) @Reeza